# Use lodash-es in nest.js

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have a monorepo with react-native, next.js and nest.js apps. They share a common library which uses lodash in some utility functions.

I want to use lodash-es in the library so that the react-native project has a smaller bundle size. But this breaks the nest.js app:

```
/Users/denniskeil/Projects/aoe2companion/node_modules/lodash-es/lodash.js:10
export { default as add } from './add.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.lodash-es (/Users/denniskeil/Projects/aoe2companion/dist/graph/webpack:/external "lodash-es":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/denniskeil/Projects/aoe2companion/dist/graph/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../data/src/api/player-matches.ts (/Users/denniskeil/Projects/aoe2companion/dist/graph/main.js:138:67)
```

Can I make this work? For next.js I use `next-transpile-modules` successfully: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2259#issuecomment-416150640